# NOPERM this user has no permissions to run the 'hmset' command

Tags: java, spring, redis

i'm trying to write a redis object on an instance of REDIS using spring-boot-starter-data-redis.
On Redis istance is deactivated the hmset and i must save object with hset.

But i only run this:

```
repository.save(myObject);
```

where repository:

```
@Repository
public interface repository extends CrudRepository<myObject, String> {}
```

and myObject:

```
@RedisHash
public class myObject{

@Id
private String sessionId;
...

}
```

How can i force spring lib to use hset instead of hmset?

Thank you,
Mik